# String and variables in SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I know that in C#, we can use variable in a string.

For example:

```
int num = 3;
string str = "hello, I have " + num + " apple";
```

How are we going to do that in an insert statement in a SQL query?

Let's say I have 2 columns in my table and they are `name` and `remarks`, and I want to write an insert statement in my stored procedure.

For example:

```
Declare @emp_no int;

Insert into employee (name, remarks) 
Values ('Joe', 'Employee's number' + @emp_no)
```

I am wondering if I can do something like this in my query?

Comment: Yes.  You can try it.

Comment: You can but make sure to set the value of your @emp_no

Comment: thank you all, that make much more senses now

Comment: Parameterized query is always prefered than standard string operation. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements

Comment: Hi, is this still open? Do you need further help?

Comment: @Shnugo, Sorry, I forgot to accept the answer, thanks for your help, problem solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this part there are several flaws:

```
Declare @emp_no int;
    Insert into employee (name, remarks) Values ('Joe', 'Employee's number' + @emp_no)
```

One after the other...

- You declare your `@emp_no` as `int` but there is no value assigned... If you concatenate SQL Strings and there is one of them NULL, the whole string will be NULL... So better use `DECLARE @emp_no INT=1` or something like `DECLARE @emp_no INT; SET @emp_no=(SELECT EmpNo FROM Employee WHERE Something unique is true)`
- The single qoute in "Employee's number" will break the string you want to set. Within a SQL String you have to double the qoutes.
- in SQL Server - other as in C# - you cannot conactenate a string and an int without a cast
- If there's no space behind the word "number", the employee's number will sit close to the word...

You might try something like this:

```
Declare @emp_no int=1;
    Insert into employee (name, remarks) 
    Values ('Joe', 'Employee''s number ' + CAST(@emp_no AS VARCHAR(10)))
```